# Going from http to https, getting "Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding"

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, iis, https

here's a problem I'm struggling with:

The configuration below used to work fine (site's binding was http, port 81). It fails now, after the site's binding was changed to be https, port 443 and use a valid server authentication certificate. The error message in Event Viewer is this:

```
 WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/25652103
 Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/services/api/oauth2' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.MakeAbsoluteUri(Uri relativeOrAbsoluteUri, Binding binding, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.ConfigureEndpointAddress(ServiceEndpointElement serviceEndpointElement, ServiceHostBase host, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.ConfigureEndpoint(StandardEndpointElement standardEndpointElement, ServiceEndpointElement serviceEndpointElement, ContextInformation context, ServiceHostBase host, ServiceDescription description, ServiceEndpoint& endpoint, Boolean omitSettingEndpointAddress)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LookupEndpoint(ServiceEndpointElement serviceEndpointElement, ContextInformation context, ServiceHostBase host, ServiceDescription description, Boolean omitSettingEndpointAddress)
   at System.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost.AddAutomaticWebHttpBindingEndpoints(ServiceHost host, IDictionary`2 implementedContracts, String multipleContractsErrorMessage, String noContractErrorMessage, String standardEndpointKind)
   at System.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost.OnOpening()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
 Process Name: w3wp
```

web.config for "api" application:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="tinCanBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00">
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="tinCanWebHttp" type="Company.RestService.TinCan.RestConfiguration.TinCanWebHttpBehaviorExtension, Company.RestService" />
        <add name="ErrorHandler" type="Company.RestService.ApiErrorHandlerBehavior, Company.RestService" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <ErrorHandler />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="tinCanBehavior">
          <tinCanWebHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="Company.RestService.TinCan.TinCanService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="tinCanBehavior" bindingConfiguration="tinCanBinding" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Company.RestService.ServiceContracts.TinCan.ITinCanService">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
      <service name="Company.RestService.CallBackRestService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="Company.RestService.ICallBackService">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false">
        </standardEndpoint>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="DSPExceptionModule" />
      <remove name="DSPThrottleModule" />
      <remove name="DSPTraceModule" />
      <remove name="DSPAuthenticationModule" />
      <add type="Company.ServiceHttpModule.DSPExceptionModule,Company.ServiceHttpModule" name="DSPExceptionModule" />
      <add type="Company.ServiceHttpModule.DSPThrottleModule,Company.ServiceHttpModule" name="DSPThrottleModule" />
      <add type="Company.ServiceHttpModule.DSPTraceModule,Company.ServiceHttpModule" name="DSPTraceModule" />
      <add type="Company.ServiceHttpModule.DSPAuthenticationModule,Company.ServiceHttpModule" name="DSPAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Common.Logging.Core" publicKeyToken="af08829b84f0328e" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.0.0.0-3.4.1.0" newVersion="3.4.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

It looks like it expects "oauth2" to be an application itself which has its own web.config while it's just a part of the route and is supposed to be handled within "api". What needs to be changed in the web.config above to make it work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use https, please refer to the following configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel >
        <services>
            <service name="WcfService30.Service1"
                     behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" >
                <endpoint address=""
                          binding="webHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="webHttpTransportSecurity"
                behaviorConfiguration="web"
                contract="WcfService30.IService1" />
                <endpoint address="mex"
                          binding="mexHttpsBinding"
                          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <bindings>
            <webHttpBinding>
                <binding name="webHttpTransportSecurity">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
            </webHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
                    <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"
                                     httpGetEnabled="false"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="web">
                    <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

[image]

To use https, you need to set the security mode to Transport.

UPDATE:

A screenshot of a binding:

[image]

Comment: Hey Ding Peng, thanks for helping out. I tried your solution - it did not work unfortunately, I'm still getting the same "Could not find a base address that matches scheme http" error.

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of a binding you have on the website you're using to test things? It's a right click on the website, then "Edit Bindings..". Please also share screenshots for going "Edit..." for each binding you get in "Site Bindings" window. Thanks!

Comment: I had to set a Transport security mode on the service binding programmatically as the service gets created and registered in the code. That worked, thanks Ding Peng